# Expand one card on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, material-ui

Currently using Material-UI-React for the first time to build out cards that expand, the issue I'm running into is when I click on one card to expand, they all expand.How can I refactor my code to only allow the card that is clicked on to expand not affecting the others?

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  card: {
    maxWidth: 300
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: '56.25%' // 16:9
  },
  expand: {
    transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('transform', {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest
    })
  },
  expandOpen: {
    transform: 'rotate(180deg)'
  }
}));

const HomePageCards = props => {
  console.log(props);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  function handleExpandClick() {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  }
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardHeader title={props.title} subheader={`User: ${props.username}`} />
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image='https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?crafts'
        title={props.title}
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant='body2' color='textSecondary' component='p'>
          {props.description}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing>
        <IconButton
          className={clsx(classes.expand, {
            [classes.expandOpen]: expanded
          })}
          onClick={handleExpandClick}
          aria-expanded={expanded}
          aria-label='show more'
        >
          <ExpandMoreIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
      <Collapse in={expanded} timeout='auto' unmountOnExit>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            <strong>Step 1:</strong>
            {props.step_1}
          </Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            <strong>Step 2:</strong>
            {props.step_2}
          </Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            <strong>Step 3:</strong>
            {props.step_3}
          </Typography>
          <Typography>
            <strong>Step 4:</strong>
            {props.step_4}
          </Typography>
          <Typography>
            <strong>Step 5:</strong>
            {props.step_5}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Collapse>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

import HomePageCards from '../HomePageCards/HomePageCards';

const HomePage = props => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    Axios.get('https://bw-how-to.herokuapp.com/guides', {
      headers: { authorization: token }
    })
      .then(res => {
        // console.log('Data', res.data);
        setUsers(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='character-list grid-view'>
      {users.map(user => (
        <HomePageCards {...user} key={user.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

I looked around but can't seem to find the solution. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your code, there is only one `Card`. Could you please also provide the code which renders multiple cards to see how you manage the state.

Comment: Yes, im mapping over an end point that reruns 6 objects.   <div className='character-list grid-view'>
      {users.map(user => (
        <HomePageCards {...user} key={user.id} />
      ))}
    </div>

Comment: Are you mapping inside of HomePageCards component or outside in the parent component?

Comment: Mapping in the parent component.

Comment: I have just created sample exampled and it works as expected, the only item which is clicked is expanded. Please check your styles, probably some bug is there. The code should work as expected as the value of the hook is different for every card and it should not affect other cards.

Comment: Thank you, just cut out the style sheet to test and it worked! Appreciate your help!

Comment: did you manage to make it work when they cards are displayed on row? I noticed it works properly only when the cards are displayed on column

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Yes, display flex on the incorrect container was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

import HomePageCards from '../HomePageCards/HomePageCards';

const HomePage = props => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    Axios.get('https://bw-how-to.herokuapp.com/guides', {
      headers: { authorization: token }
    })
      .then(res => {
        // console.log('Data', res.data);
        setUsers(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='character-list grid-view'>
      {users.map(user => (
        <HomePageCards {...user}
```

1. List item Recent subscribers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).