# React and Material UI: how can I expand only one single card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React and Material UI in order to show some mapped cards mapped. When I try to expand a card, all the cards are expanded at the same time. I figured out that I have to pass an index inside my "handleExpandClick" function, but still not working. Maybe I did it some kind of typo.

I found this question [Expand one card on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699182/expand-one-card-on-click) that regards the same problem, but seems not to be applied to my situation.

Here my piece of code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    marginBottom: 15
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: "56.25%" // 16:9
  },
  expand: {
    transform: "rotate(0deg)",
    marginLeft: "auto",
    transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest
    })
  },
  expandOpen: {
    transform: "rotate(180deg)"
  },
  avatar: {
    width: 90
  },
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(0.5)
    }
  },
  list: {
    width: 200
  }
}));

const ItininerariesList = ({ itineraries, activities }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  let path = window.location.pathname;
  let currentId = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

  const itinerariesPerCity = itineraries.filter(
    itiner => itiner.city_id === currentId
  );


  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };


  return (
    <Fragment>
      {itinerariesPerCity.map((itinerary, i) => (
        <Card className={classes.card} key={itinerary._id}>
          <CardHeader
            avatar={
              <Grid
                container
                direction="column"
                justify="flex-start"
                alignItems="center"
                className={classes.avatar}
              >
                <Avatar
                  aria-label="user"
                  alt={itinerary.profile_name}
                  src={itinerary.profile_img}
                >
                  <PersonIcon />
                </Avatar>
                <Typography variant="caption" component="p">
                  {itinerary.profile_name}
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            }
            action={
              <IconButton aria-label="settings">
                <MoreVertIcon />
              </IconButton>
            }
            title={itinerary.title}
            subheader={itinerary.sub_title}
          />

          <CardContent>

          </CardContent>
          <CardActions disableSpacing>
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              <FavoriteIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="share">
              <ShareIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              className={clsx(classes.expand, {
                [classes.expandOpen]: expanded
              })}
              onClick={() => handleExpandClick()}
              aria-expanded={expanded}
              aria-label="show more"
            >
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </CardActions>
          <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <CardContent>
              <ActivitiesList
                activities={activities}
                itineraryId={itinerary._id}
              />
            </CardContent>
          </Collapse>
        </Card>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ItininerariesList;
```

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You only have one `expanded` state property that you apply to all your cards. You need to keep track of *which card* is expanded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the expand handler you indeed have to pass the index. And also use it in the state.
Something like it:

```js
const [expandedId, setExpandedId] = React.useState(-1);

...

  const handleExpandClick = (i) => {
    setExpandedId(expandedId === i ? -1 : i);
  };

  ...


          <CardContent />
          <CardActions disableSpacing>
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              <FavoriteIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="share">
              <ShareIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton

              onClick={() => handleExpandClick(i)}
              aria-expanded={expandedId === i}
              aria-label="show more"
            >
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </CardActions>
          <Collapse in={expandedId === i} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <CardContent>
              <div>ActivitiesList</div>
            </CardContent>
          </Collapse>
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sara-wswrn