# CSS Grid Cards Are linked Horizontally

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, css-grid

I am using Material UI Grid as an container to Cards. I have two columns of cards and I have a function when someone clicks one of those cards it expands vertically. Everything works fine but problem is when I click to expand the card the parallel card also expands which is next to it. How can I prevent this behaviour ? Thanks in advance.

```
import { FC } from "react"
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid"

export const ExamoCardsGrid: FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Grid spacing={8} container justifyContent="center">
      {children}
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

Here is the snippet

```
    import { memo } from "react"
import * as React from "react"
import { useIntl } from "react-intl"
import AccessTimeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AccessTime"
import MoreHorizIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreHoriz"
import Box from "@mui/material/Box"
import Card from "@mui/material/Card"
import MuiChip from "@mui/material/Chip"
import Collapse from "@mui/material/Collapse"
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid"
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack"
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography"

import { ExamoTypesEnum } from "src/common/types/examo-types-enum"
import { useAssignType } from "src/common/types/use-assign-type"
import { useAppSelector } from "src/redux/hooks"
import { ExamoAssignTo } from "src/ui/examo/examo-assign-to"
import { ExamoStartDialogBtn } from "src/ui/examo/examo-start-btn"

interface props {
  duration: string | null
  title: string
  tags: string[] | null
  numberOfQuestions: number | null
  isLoading: boolean
  handleStart: () => void
  useAssign: useAssignType
  isStartButtonDisabled: boolean
  isResuming: boolean
  type: ExamoTypesEnum
  i: number
}

export const ExamoCard = memo(
  ({
    duration,
    tags,
    title,
    isLoading,
    numberOfQuestions,
    isStartButtonDisabled,
    isResuming,
    type,
    handleStart,
    useAssign,
    i,
  }: props) => {
    const intl = useIntl()
    const user = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth)
    const durationHours = duration?.split(":")[0]
    const durationMinutes = duration?.split(":")[1]
    // const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false)
    const [expandedId, setExpandedId] = React.useState(-1)

    // const handleExpandClick = () => {
    //   setExpanded(!expanded)
    // }
    const handleExpandClick = (i: number) => {
      setExpandedId(expandedId === i ? -1 : i)
    }

    const PreventParentOnClick = (event: any) => event.stopPropagation()

    let buttonOpacity = 0
    let buttonHeight: number | string = 0

    if (expandedId === i) {
      buttonOpacity = 1
      buttonHeight = "auto"
    }

    let timeDisplayAttribute = ""

    if (expandedId === i) {
      timeDisplayAttribute = "none"
    }

    return (
      <Grid item xs={12} lg={6}>
        <Card
          onClick={() => handleExpandClick(i)}
          aria-expanded={expandedId === i}
          elevation={2}
          sx={{
            padding: "1rem",
            height: "100%",
            borderRadius: "1rem",
            border: "solid 1px var(--palette-grey-400)",
            transition: "all 0.1s ease-in-out",
            ":hover": {
              backgroundColor: "var(--palette-grey-100)",
              cursor: "pointer",
            },
          }}
        >
          <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="space-between">
            <Stack
              justifyContent="space-around"
              gap={numberOfQuestions ? 1.5 : 6}
            >
              <Typography
                variant="h5"
                sx={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap", wordBreak: "break-all" }}
              >
                {title}
              </Typography>
              <Collapse in={expandedId === i} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <Stack direction="row" gap={4}>
                  {numberOfQuestions && (
                    <Typography variant="h6">
                      {`${numberOfQuestions}  ${intl.formatMessage({
                        id: "questions",
                        defaultMessage: "Questions",
                      })}`}
                    </Typography>
                  )}
                  <Typography
                    whiteSpace="nowrap"
                    variant="h6"
                  >{`${durationHours}h ${durationMinutes}m`}</Typography>
                </Stack>
                <Stack
                  direction="row"
                  sx={{ flexWrap: "wrap", gap: 1, marginTop: "1rem" }}
                >
                  {tags?.map((t, index) => (
                    <MuiChip
                      key={index}
                      label={t}
                      variant="filled"
                      sx={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                      color="secondary"
                      size="small"
                    />
                  ))}
                </Stack>
              </Collapse>
            </Stack>

            <Stack
              justifyContent="space-between"
              alignItems="center"
              spacing={1}
            >
              <MoreHorizIcon />
              <Box
                onClick={PreventParentOnClick}
                sx={{
                  transition: "height 0ms 400ms, opacity 400ms 0ms",
                  opacity: buttonOpacity,
                  height: buttonHeight,
                  overflow: "hidden",
                }}
              >
                {user.role === "Operator" && (
                  <ExamoAssignTo useAssign={useAssign} title={title} />
                )}
              </Box>
              <Stack
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent="end"
                direction="row"
                gap={1}
                display={timeDisplayAttribute}
              >
                <AccessTimeIcon />
                <Typography
                  whiteSpace="nowrap"
                  variant="h6"
                >{`${durationHours}h ${durationMinutes}m`}</Typography>
              </Stack>
              <Box onClick={PreventParentOnClick}>
                <ExamoStartDialogBtn
                  type={type}
                  isResuming={isResuming}
                  handleStart={handleStart}
                  isLoading={isLoading}
                  isDisabled={isStartButtonDisabled}
                />
              </Box>
            </Stack>
          </Stack>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    )
  },
)
```

Comment: The problem isn't clear. Can you share the snippet?

Comment: @Akib I have edited my post and added the actual code. But the main problem is in the first code. for example I have two cards staying next to each other like a - b. when i expand the a card it becomes A that's cool but next to it the b card also expands and becomes B that's the problem.

Comment: Got it, it's happening for align-items: center; Try to avoid it.

Comment: @Nika it seems it has nothing to do with the Grid or any container, but that the cards are listening to the same 'expand' from the state. Check this post I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58953627/react-and-material-ui-how-can-i-expand-only-one-single-card

Comment: @Akib I have tried to avoid it but it's still the same. looks like it really has nothing to do with it. I'll try now Akis answer. Still Thanks Akib.

Comment: @Akis I have edited my code snippet. I have tried solution that is given in your link but the problem is I don't map as there is shown and don't know how to pass that "i" as a parameter, i have tried as shown in the snippet but terminal says warning: "i" is already declared in the upper scope which is in line 58 where am writing handleClick function and pass "i" as a parameter. You would be lifesaver if you could help me how to fix that.

Comment: @Nika the "i" will come from the index of a loop. Seems you are passing the children which are your Card components? A complete code sandbox would be very helpful

Comment: @Akis yes i am passing children in the first code snippet which are my Card Components.  Every code connected to that i have already uploaded in first and second code snippets Sorry,. i don't get what you mean in complete code sandbox ?

Comment: I mean to create an example in codesandbox that we can replicate the problem. Above I could tell you what the issue is, but if I have a working example it will be easier to provide you a solution. Thanks